# Downloading file is so slow

Tags: java, performance, download

I tried same file with Opera browser and Java code.

Opera Browser is giving nearly 2 MB/s speed but Java code gives not more than 400 KB/s. What's wrong with my code?

I guess I'm doing it wrong with reading with BufferedReader but I have no idea why it does happen and how can I fix.

PS: I'm only speed-testing, not running the file. I know that it's a binary file, does this make any difference at speed?

```
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpURLConnection uri = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://speedtest.tele2.net/3MB.zip").openConnection();
            uri.setRequestMethod("GET");
            uri.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            InputStream ent = uri.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ent, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
```

Comment: You can read a file at about 100 MB/s with BufferedReader, I would worry more about reading a binary file as text as that won't work. You should read it as binary.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it's only for speedtesting, not for running, so I guess it's OK to do it?

Comment: @AlperÖzdemir not really, the BufferedReader has to do work to look for newlines in the read data. Doing a binary transfer most definitely is more representative of what Opera will be doing under the hood. Plus you can simply shove more data at once, reading in say 4k or 8k at a time.

Comment: @Gimby yeah, thanks for information. Also reading as binary more useful I guess, even the text files, right?

Comment: Using an unreasonably tiny buffer size of 8 certainly will not help your performance.

Comment: @VGR what is your suggestion? Code will run on Android.

Comment: My suggestion is to follow the accepted answer for this question.  In the future, when using BufferedReader, just use the single-argument constructor and avoid specifying a buffer size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use binary download for binary files, when I run this I get

```
public class DownloadMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection uri = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://speedtest.tele2.net/3MB.zip").openConnection();
        uri.setRequestMethod("GET");
        uri.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        InputStream ent = uri.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int len; (len = ent.read(bytes)) > 0; )
            baos.write(bytes, 0, len);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to read %.3f MB of data%n",
                time / 1e3, baos.toByteArray().length / 1e6);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.541 seconds to read 3.146 MB of data
```

which is almost 6 MB/s

If you ignore the fact the file is binary, just for performance comparison purposes.

```
public class DownloadMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection uri = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://speedtest.tele2.net/3MB.zip").openConnection();
        uri.setRequestMethod("GET");
        uri.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        InputStream ent =uri.getInputStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ent, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        char[] chars = new char[8192];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0; )
            sw.write(chars, 0, len);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to read %.3f MB of data%n",
                time / 1e3, sw.toString().length() / 1e6);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.548 seconds to read 3.146 MB of data
```

So it might be slightly slower, or just random variation.

By comparison, using StringBuilder and reading one line at a time could be slower, but not dramatically

```
Took 0.555 seconds to read 3.146 MB of data
```

Comment: @AlperÖzdemir I added a test using your original loop and it was only slightly slower.